# Shell script to check if a paragraph exist in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file,

```
Published 3EO's  
Save completed  
Trade saving save successful for 123

Published 3EO's  
Save completed  
Trade saving save successful for 234



Published 4EO's  
Save completed  
Trade saving save successful for trade
5666688|000|b
```

My Question is I want to write a script which checks that following paragraph exist or not also I want to store the paragraph in a variable for comparision.

```
Published 3EO's  
Save completed  
Trade saving save successful for 123
```

I have written like this

```
cat $file | grep -A 2 "Published 3EO's"
```

where $file contains the original paragraphs.

The problem is, It Returns more than two value, 1st and 2nd Paragraph.
But I want only one paragraph for which i am looking a match.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have an exact same question (unaccepted with an answer available) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586948/shell-script-to-check-if-a-paragraph-stream-of-lines-exist-in-a-file? again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed ;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ output=$(sed -n "/Published 3EO's/N;{/Save completed/N;{/Trade saving save successful for 123/p}}" file)
$ echo "$output"
Published 3EO's
Save completed
Trade saving save successful for 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk "/Published 3EO's/ && /Save completed/ && /and so on.../" RS='' file.txt
```

Setting `RS` to an empty string is a special feature. It will split the text into paragraphs.

From `man awk`:

> If RS is set to the null string, then records
>          are separated by blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as a  field  separator,
>          in addition to whatever value FS may have.

Comment: Though I did not understand it properly, I would like to ask a question. What if Paragraph which i have to match is 3rd or any except 1st?

Comment: Unwanted paragraph is printed here.

Comment: @RajivRai You can use the logical *and* operator `&&` to combine multiple conditions. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, But I got your point. Thank you.